# How Can I Create a NTFS Directory Redirect in Windows 7 Enterprise?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, file-management, mklink

I am using [DeepFreeze](http://www.faronics.com/en/Products/DeepFreeze/DeepFreezeEducation.aspx) to keep my C:\ drive from getting corrupted, but I need the "C:\Users" directory to be redirected (like a virtual directory or alias) to "D:\Users" so that basic changes to user profiles can be preserved between boots.

Do explain further, whenever any application attempts to access "C:\Users" (for reading OR writing), the file system should step in and perform the ACTUAL operation on "D:\Users" instead. This would mean that all of the user profile information would be stored on the D:\ drive, but the operating system would think that the information was still on the C:\ drive.

I am currently reading [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) that talks about the "mklink" command, but the article doesn't describe what the various types of links are. I don't know which one will give me what I want.

I assume I want either a Directory Symbolic Link or a Directory Junction, but I'm not sure what the difference is between the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Directory Junction is what you want, that will redirect you to the new location.

To move a location of other Windows folders, consider using the `mklink` command of windows

Here's a simple tutorial on how to do this:
http://windows7themes.net/windows-7-mklink-command-use-to-create-symbolic-links.html

You may face an error if you were to do

```
mklink /J "C:\Program Files" "H:\Program Files"
```

as it's complaining about C:\Program Files existing.

Here's a possible way you could go around this issue:
https://web.archive.org/web/20111224183215/http://tuts4tech.net/2009/08/05/windows-7-move-the-users-and-program-files-directories-to-a-different-partition/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is of any help
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/18629-user-folders-change-default-location.html

[I have not tried this myself]
Edit: Maybe this then, see OPTION TWO (in the middle of the page)
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I am looking for. I need something that will redirect the ENTIRE C:\Users folder, regardless of what profile is being used.